# Hey, how do I add a toggle system to my discord bot? [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to add some sort of toggle system to my discord bot that would have $active and the bot would look for test, and then $deactive to stop looking for test, I don't know where to start besides this.

```js
let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
case 'active':
  msg.channel.send("Activated listening!")
break;
case 'deactive':
  msg.channel.send("Deactivated listening!")
break;
```

Comment: What does _look for test_ mean? Do you need message collectors? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

Comment: By look for I mean `if(msg.content.includes('test')`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `case` you need to declare a switch first of all. Based on your comment, I will provide an answer, but let me know if this isn't what you were after.

```js
let listenState = 0; // Change to 1 for it to be on by default
let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
switch(args[0]) {
    case "active":
        state = 1;
        msg.channel.send("Activated listening!");
        break;
    case "deactive":
        state = 0;
        msg.channel.send("Deactivated listening!");
        break;
}
```

`args[0]` will get `active` or `deactive` in a command like this: `!active`. You can then check if `state` is equal to 0 or 1 to see if you should be listening

```js
if(state == 1) {
    // Your code here
}
```

You can use a `default` case if it matches none of those, like this:

```js
let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
switch(args[0]) {
    case "active":
        msg.channel.send("Activated listening!");
        break;
    case "deactive":
        msg.channel.send("Deactivated listening!");
        break;
    default:
        msg.channel.send("Command not found");
        break;
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, sorry I'm really bad at words. What I'm needing help with is a toggle system, like when you use !active it sends the message, but it also turns on another command. So when I run the bot, it won't look for "test" but when I run !active it will start looking for "test". I asked about it in the djs server and was told I need to use a database but that's way outside of my abilities, because I've never done it before.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark this as correct if it has worked for you, to help other users out. Thanks